# How to map entire JSON object as value into new JSON key using JOLT?

Tags: json, jolt

my goal is to map a JSON object into as value in a new JSON object key. Such as example:

My starting JSON:

```
{
 "old_key_1" : "some_json_structure_1",
 "old_key_2" : "some_json_structure_2",
 "old_key_3" : "some_json_structure_3"
}
```

My goal JSON:

```
{
 "new_key_1" : 
  {
    "old_key_1" : "some_json_structure_1",
    "old_key_2" : "some_json_structure_2",
    "old_key_3" : "some_json_structure_3"
  }
}
```

How is it possible using JOLT: if I understand well I have to use a shift spec but I didn't understand how?

Can anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping into new object:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "new_key_1.&" //the "&" means go up the tree 0 levels, grab what is there and subtitute it in
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Magda. It worked: I got this solution before but I forgot to put the solution in the question. So thanks doing this for me and thanks for the solution!